# Force Lyx to use junction points

Tags: pdftex, pdf, export

I have the familiar problem with pdflatex not able to export files that are saved in directories containing spaces to pdf. The solution I found (other than saving everything under a different folder) is to edit the Latex file before exporting, 
changing the path name to its junction name.
This is the line that I'm changing:
\def\input@path{{\detokenize{%path%}}}

I was wondering if there is a way you could make Lyx do that automatically.
Alternatively, any other solution to this "spaces problem" would be great.
Thanks!

PS - using MikTex 2.9 console (all packages up to date) and Lyx 2.3.4.3

Comment: What do you mean by "exporting from a directory"? And what do you edit? (With a current latex pathes with spaces should normally work).

Comment: Exporting in Lyx seems to refer to "exporting to other formats". However, your question sound build process-related? Could you please clarify what you mean by "exporting"? Thanks!

Comment: I added some details, hope this clears up the situation

Comment: Any other solution ? The safest, easiest and not only for LyX: Never ever use spaces in directory names.  
You deny of use sentence as names  and all your sins will be forgiven  (well, not really,  but it will make your life easier).